# find by query and push to array in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I store data in the elastic search like this:

```
{
"_index": "my_index",
"_type": "doc",
"_id": "6lDquGEBFRQVe0x93eHk",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"ID_Number": "6947503728601",
"Userrname":"Jack.m07",
"name": "Jack",
"photos": ["img/one.png"]
}
}
```

I want find user by `ID_Number` and push new value to `Photos`

e.g)

```
"photos": ["img/one.png","img/two.png"]
```

How can I implement this? What is the query?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve... Also provide a full error traceback.

Comment: Take a look at update_by_query type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer,this is the query

```
POST my_index/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.photos.add(params.new_photos)",
    "params": {
      "new_photos": "img/two.png"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "ID_Number": "6947503728601"
    }
  }
}
```